# Why the elements of an imported list are considered as one in the new list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need to choose an external list (u_list.py or h_list.py), import this list and print each element of this list separately with an additional text ("something").
I've tried everything but the list I get (my_list = []) includes all the elements as one.

```
choose = input('Choose list: ')
my_list = []

if choose == "u":
  from u_list import u_list
  my_list.append(u_list)

if choose == "h":
  from h_list import h_list
  my_list.append(h_list)

for i in my_list:
    print (i, "something")
```

Output:
`['FB', 'NFLX', 'AMZN'] something`

But what I need is this:

```
FB something                                                       
NFLX something                                                     
AMZN something
```

Please help me! Oink

Comment: You need to `extend` the list

Comment: This would be a lot simpler if your conditions just did `from u_list import u_list as my_list` and `from h_list import h_list as my_list`.

Comment: Thank you! Now it is working like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`list.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)?

```py
choose = input('Choose list: ')
my_list = []

if choose == "u":
  from u_list import u_list
  my_list.extend(u_list)

if choose == "h":
  from h_list import h_list
  my_list.extend(h_list)

for i in my_list:
    print (i, "something")
```

Should print:

```
FB something                                                       
NFLX something                                                     
AMZN something
```

Alternatively, if the logic is simple and you only import and use one list, you could simply set `my_list` to whatever gets imported:

```py
choose = input('Choose list: ')
my_list = []

if choose == "u":
  from u_list import u_list
  my_list = u_list

if choose == "h":
  from h_list import h_list
  my_list = h_list

for i in my_list:
    print (i, "something")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the entire imported list to `my_list`, rather than importing the *elements* of the imported list to `my_list`. Put another way, you are creating a two-dimensional list.

The simplest and shortest fix is to put an asterisk (`*`) in front of the call to append, like `my_list.append(*h_list)`. Alternatively, for a beginner, it might be more clear to write:

```
if choose == "h":
    from h_list import h_list
    for new_element in h_list:
        my_list.append(new_element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacemy_`list.append(u_list)` and `my_list.append(h_list)` with `my_list = u_list` and `my_list = h_list`

Append will create create list inside list and therefore something get appended to the list instead of each element in the list.